# Choice columns fail to sync between SharePoint 2013 and client applications Excel 2010

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, excel

We have 2 columns:

- Subject ( choice)
- Document ( choice)

When we try to edit the file in excel in the image as we see **Subject** has changed in Excel as a text and not a choice list and if we write any text, it will be changed in SharePoint

[image]

Can anyone suggest me a workaround for this?